# incomplete type 'TextureLoader' used in nested name specifier

Tags: c++

I've got this class

```
#ifndef WRAPPED_TEXTURE_H
#define WRAPPED_TEXTURE_H

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include "../ui/utils/texture.h"

// color keying - CHROMA KEY!!!!

class WrappedTexture {

public:
    WrappedTexture() {
        raw_texture = NULL;
        width = 0;
        height = 0;
        bound_renderer = NULL;
    }
    WrappedTexture(SDL_Renderer* bound_renderer) {
        raw_texture = NULL;
        width = 0;
        height = 0;
        this->bound_renderer = bound_renderer;
    }
    ~WrappedTexture() {
        printf("Freeing resources!");
        free();
    }
    void free() {
        if (raw_texture != NULL) {
            SDL_DestroyTexture(raw_texture);
            raw_texture = NULL;
            width = 0;
            height = 0;
        }
    }
    void load_from_file(std::string path) {
        free();
        TextureLoader::load_texture_chroma(path, bound_renderer, NULL, std::vector<Uint8> { 0, 0xFF, 0xFF}, *this);
    }
    void render(int x, int y) {
        SDL_Rect render_frame = { x, y, width, height };
        SDL_RenderCopy(bound_renderer, raw_texture, NULL, &render_frame);
    }

    int get_width() {
        return width;
    }
    int get_height() {
        return height;
    }
    void set_width_height(int width, int height) {
        this->width = width;
        this->height = height;
    }
    void set_raw_texture(SDL_Texture* raw_texture) {
        this->raw_texture = raw_texture;
    }

private:
    SDL_Texture* raw_texture;
    int width;
    int height;
    SDL_Renderer* bound_renderer;
};

#endif
```

And I've got utility class with useful for me functions.

```
#ifndef TEXTURE_H
#define TEXTURE_H

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <vector>

#include "image.h"

#include "../../domain/WrappedTexture.h"

class TextureLoader {
public:
    static WrappedTexture *create_wrapped_texture(int width, int height, SDL_Texture* raw, SDL_Renderer* render) {
        WrappedTexture* wt = new WrappedTexture(render);
        wt->set_width_height(width, height);
        wt->set_raw_texture(raw);
        return wt;
    }
    static SDL_Texture* load_texture_chroma(std::string path,
            SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_Surface* screen_surface,
            std::vector<Uint8> pixelColor, WrappedTexture& output) {
        int width = -1;
        int height = -1;

        SDL_Texture* new_texture = NULL;
        SDL_Surface* loaded_surface = ImageLoader::load_image(path,
                screen_surface);
        if (loaded_surface == NULL) {
            printf("Unable to load image %s! SDL_image Error: %s\n",
                    path.c_str(), IMG_GetError());
        } else {
            SDL_SetColorKey(loaded_surface, SDL_TRUE,
                    SDL_MapRGB(loaded_surface->format, pixelColor[0],
                            pixelColor[1], pixelColor[2]));
            new_texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,
                    loaded_surface);
            if (new_texture == NULL) {
                printf("Unable to create texture %s! SDL Error: %s\n",
                        path.c_str(), SDL_GetError());
            } else {
                width = loaded_surface->w;
                height = loaded_surface->h;
            }
            SDL_FreeSurface(loaded_surface);
        }

        if (width != -1 && height != -1 && &output != NULL) {
            output = *TextureLoader::create_wrapped_texture(width, height, new_texture, renderer);
        }
        return new_texture;
    }
};

#endif
```

But I've got error in the line *`incomplete type 'TextureLoader' used in nested name specifier`*

```
void load_from_file(std::string path) {
    free();
    TextureLoader::load_texture_chroma(path, bound_renderer, NULL, std::vector<Uint8> { 0, 0xFF, 0xFF}, *this); // error
}
```

I was trying to declare `class TextureLoader` in `WrappedTexture` class and tried `class WrappedTexture` in `TextureLoader` but it didn't help.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably your reference to the class, before it is completely declared:

```
output = *TextureLoader::create_wrapped_texture(width, height, new_texture, renderer);
```

At this point the class `TextureLoader` is still not completely declared. Try to move the function definitions to a `.cpp` file. Is there a reason why all your functions are implemented in the headers?

Comment: Tsk. Indeed. I forgot that it's initialization group method. As for headers... Well I am just lazy to separate it for now. Don't wan't to create bunch of files until I finalize everything.